# When using Wi-Fi in a crowded/noisy area, why is 40MHz bandwidth slower than 20MHz?

Tags: wireless-networking

When I test my Wi-Fi in an area which has many neighbor APs, I find that HT40 is noticeably slower than HT20 (which is supposed to be 2 times faster in a clean/quiet area), why?

Comment: 40Mhz wide wifi bandwidth consumes two adjacent channels, traffic on either channel can interfere.

Comment: Because the signal quality is degraded because of the noise that exist.  As you point out, HT40 is suppose to be 2 times faster, if there is a low amount of interferance.

Comment: Yes I know it must have relation with additional interference, but it's even slower than HT20? I mean in the worst case, the additional 20Mhz is completely unusable, it should be the same speed as HT20, right?

Comment: In theory it should be the same speed, in the real world outside of a controlled environment, 40 Mhz can perform worst then 20 Mhz.

Comment: @Sam Imagine if you're sending small chunks of data where most of the time is spent getting ready to send. So bandwidth won't affect the speed much. But getting interfered with twice as often will mean you spent twice as much time getting ready to send.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I guess you're the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Per the IEEE 802.11 standards, 40MHz mode is really supposed to be 20/40MHz mode, always backwards compatible with 20MHz-only devices. But I've seen some products that seem to have a 20MHz-only mode, a 20/40MHz mode, and a 40MHz-only mode. If you have equipment like that, and you've put it into 40MHz-only mode, then it can only transmit when the whole 40MHz-wide swath of bandwidth is free, and it can be interfered with by anything in the whole 40MHz wide channel.

If your equipment is in 20/40MHz mode and still performs worse than in 20MHz-only mode on the same control channel, then you probably have poorly implemented (buggy) equipment that is failing to fall back to using 20MHz transmissions when 40MHz transmissions aren't reliable.